# Evaluate the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^{4})}{1+x^{2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do I evaluate this integral ? I am a student who just studied calculus 1 and recently definite integral.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^{4})}{1+x^{2}} dx
$$

I substituted both $x = \tan t$ and $x = \frac1{t}$ but could not proceed further.

Comment: Is contour integration allowed?

Comment: I don't know what it is @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad

Comment: But what's the context here? Is this a random integral you found online, or is it part of a problem sheet? This indicates how difficult the solution might be. Since you say "Calculus $1$", contour integration is too hard.... *unless* this is a random problem. So please give context, this is expected on this site

Comment: @SavageTomato It is complex integration, kind of advanced. But since you don't know it we shouldn't be using it in an answer so you could understand.

Comment: @FShrike it is the part of sheet

Comment: @KamalSaleh i know complex number and have studied it

Comment: Which techniques have you been taught so far to evaluate definite integrals?

Comment: @SavageTomato Yes, but Calculus with complex numbers is different. It has contours and residues and other advanced stuff. But it shouldn't take long to learn.

Comment: @SavageTomato contour integration isn't same as complex numbers

Comment: @SavageTomato have you learnt complex analysis..then maybe I can give a try to this question

Comment: Here is the first video of a playlist on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEu5ie25U0Y&list=PLBh2i93oe2qtIc75sLYaVEBt0QNqVbdmZ

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad If OP doesn't know contour integration they probably don't know complex analysis.

Comment: Have you heard of Feynman's technique?

Comment: @KamalSaleh feynman technique isn't doing much job imo...someone posted a soln based on that

Comment: Numerator can be split into $\ln(x^2 + \sqrt{2} x + 1) + \ln(x^2 - \sqrt{2} x + 1)$, which might be helpful.

Comment: this is even worse... @eyeballfrog

Comment: Some similar integrals: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4411366/evaluating-int-infty-infty-frac-lnx4x21x41dx/) [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689192/evaulate-int-infty-infty-frac-lnx21x4x21dx/) [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509963/int-0-infty-frac-lnx8x42x21x21dx-and-int-0-infty-frac1/)

Comment: For the sake of another answer, may we use contour integration? :)

Comment: @KamalSaleh yes u can ... it will increase my knowledge and ability to solve problem

Comment: Contour integral there are four branch points, and if take the upper half plane there are two branch points. A V-shape antenna contour should work.

Comment: In the future, or even on this post, we suggest expanding on what you tried. You say you tried those two substitutions, so you could show how you used them and added in more steps. If you just say you tried one or two techniques without explaining how, it's not a good fit for a question on this site.

Comment: @Accelerator i wold definitely do that but i am new and i dont know how to write latex... and that why i use online tools to do that and that takes a lot of time.

Comment: You can use [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as a tutorial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A polynomial of the form $1+x^{2n}$ can always be written as the product of $n$ quadratic factors of the form $1-2x\cos\theta + x^2$. So that suggests we consider the integral
$$
I(\theta) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\ln(1-2x\cos\theta+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx.
$$
Now, if we differentiate this with respect to $\theta$, we'll get a rational function of $x$, and the integral can then be evaluated through partial fractions:
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(\theta) &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2x\sin\theta}{(1-2x\cos\theta+x^2)(1+x^2)}dx 
\\&=&\tan\theta\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{1-2x\cos\theta+x^2}- \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)dx
\\ &=& \pi\frac{1-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\pi\frac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin\theta} = \pi\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln(1+\sin\theta).
\end{eqnarray}
This gives us the $\theta$ dependence of $I$, but we need the value of $I$ at a particular $\theta$ to set the constant of integtration. We can evaluate the case $\theta = \pi/2$ with clever use of trigonometric identities and variable substitutions:
\begin{eqnarray}
I\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)& = &\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} = -4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos\phi)d\phi = -4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin\phi)d\phi \\
&=& -2\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin\phi)d\phi =-4\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin 2\psi)d\psi = -4\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(2\sin\psi\cos\psi)d\psi 
\\ &=& -2\pi\ln 2-4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos\psi)d\psi-4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin\psi)d\psi
\\ &=& -2\pi\ln 2 + 2I\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Thus $I(\pi/2) = 2\pi \ln2$, and we have
$$
I(\theta) = \pi\ln[2(1+\sin\theta)].
$$
From here it's easy to show
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x^4)}{1+x^2}dx = I\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + I\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) = 2\pi\ln(2+\sqrt{2})
$$

Comment: @SavageTomato Notice that $\log(1 + x^4) = \log[(x^2 + \sqrt2 x + 1)(x^2 - \sqrt2 x + 1)] = \log (x^2 + \sqrt2 x + 1) + \log (x^2 - \sqrt2 x + 1)$.

Answer (score 9):

Factorize $1+x^4= (1+i x^2)(1-ix^2)$ and then utilize the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\ln(1+ax^2)}{1+x^2}dx= 2\pi\ln(1+a^{\frac12})
$$
to obtain

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln (1+x^{4})}{1+x^2}dx
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln (1+i x^{2})}{1+x^{2}}+\frac{\ln (1-i x^{2})}{1+x^{2}}\  dx\\
&=2\pi \ln\left[(1+i^{\frac12})(1+(-i)^{\frac12})\right]=2\pi\ln (2+\sqrt2)
\end{align}

Comment: How do you choose the branch cut?

Comment: @GGplay The stated identity holds for real positive $a$ and it carries over by analytic continuation and the only choices of logarithm that make the analytic continuation valid (with regards to the square root) are logarithms which assign the principal arguments to $i$, $-i$. But that's all worth a note in the answer, I agree

Comment: How u evaluate the final/last step integral ?

Comment: Before applying the referenced formula, you need to demonstrate the analytic continuation, which is much far away beyond the OP's requirement.

Comment: The identity
$$
      \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\ln(1 + ax^2)}{1 + x^2}dx = 2\pi\ln(1 + a^{1/2})
$$ raises more questions than answer imo

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn To be fair, it can be justified, under a suitable interpretation of $()^{1/2}$

Comment: @SavageTomato -$$\ln\left[(1+i^{\frac12})(1+(-i)^{\frac12})\right]
= \ln(2+e^{i\frac\pi 4}+ e^{-i\frac\pi 4})\\
=\ln(2+2\cos\frac\pi4)= \ln (2+\sqrt2)
$$

Comment: @Quanto no the step before that

Comment: @SavageTomato $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln (1+i x^{2})}{1+x^{2}}dx=2\pi \ln(1+i^{1/2})
$, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln (1-i x^{2})}{1+x^{2}}dx=2\pi \ln(1+(-i)^{1/2})
$

Comment: @Quanto thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9):

Hint: Under $x=\tan t$, you have
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^{4})}{1+x^{2}} dx\\
&=&\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\ln(1+\tan^4t)dt\\
&=&\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\cos^4+\sin^4t)dt-4\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\cos t)dt\\
&=&\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\ln\bigg(\frac34+\frac14\cos(4t)\bigg)dt-4\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\cos t)dt\\
&=&\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\ln\bigg(3+\cos(4t)\bigg)dt+2\pi\ln2\\
&=&2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln(3+\cos t)dt+2\pi\ln2\\
\end{eqnarray}
Here
$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\cos t)dt=-\pi\ln2 $$
is used. For the first term, you can define
$$ I(a)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln(a+\cos t)dt, a\ge 1 $$
and then use Feyman's trick to get it. I omit the detail. ([Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln (1+\cos x)\, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590783/evaluating-int-0-pi-ln-1-cos-x-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Evaluate $\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}} \log(1+\cos x)\, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909712/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log1-cos-x-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Answer (score 7):

I don't see how to evaluate this integral using the techniques from a typical first integral calculus course.

We'll use two standard techniques: Differentiating under the integral sign, and applying the Residue Theorem to an appropriate contour.

Consider the family $I(a)$ of integrals defined by the
$$I(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log[1 + (a x)^4]\,dx}{1 + x^2}$$
Our integral is $I(1)$.

Differentiating $I(a)$ with respect to $a$ and rearranging gives
$$I'(a)
= 4 a^3 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^4 \,dx}{(1 + a x^4) (1 + x^2)}
= \frac{4 a^3}{1 + a^4} \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 - 1}{1 + a^4 x^4}\,dx\right]$$

The first integral in brackets is $\arctan x \vert_{-\infty}^\infty = \frac\pi2$. To evaluate the second integral, we could use the method of partial fractions to decompose the integral and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but the antiderivative is messy. So we instead apply the Residue Theorem to a standard semicircular contour $\Gamma_R$. The residues of $f(z) := \frac{z^2 - 1}{1 + a^4 z^4}$ inside $\Gamma_R$ (for large enough $R$) are at $\exp \frac{\pi i}4, \exp \frac{3\pi i}4$:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z), \frac{\exp\frac{\pi i}{4}}{a}\right)
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt 2 a^3} \left[(1 + a^2) - (1 - a^2) i\right] \\
\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z), \frac{\exp\frac{3\pi i}{4}}{a}\right)
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt 2 a^3} \left[-(1 + a^2) - (1 - a^2) i\right]
\end{align}
So,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2 - 1}{1 + a^4 x^4} \,dx = 2 \pi i \sum_{z_i} \operatorname{Res}\left(f(z), z_i\right) = \frac{\pi (1 - a^2)}{\sqrt 2 a^3}.$$
[image]

Assembling the above ingredients gives
$$I'(a) = 2 \pi \frac{\sqrt 2 + 2 a}{1 + \sqrt 2 a + a^2} ,$$ so our integral has value
\begin{multline}\require{cancel}
I(1)
= I(1) - \cancelto{0}{I(0)} = \int_0^1 I'(a) \,da = 2 \pi \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt 2 + 2 a}{1 + \sqrt 2 a + a^2} \,da \\ = 2 \pi \log(1 + \sqrt 2 a + a^2)\vert_0^1 = \boxed{2 \pi \log(2 + \sqrt 2)} .\end{multline}

Answer (score 3):

Using the identity $\ln \left(x^2+y^2\right)=2 \Re(\ln (x+y i))$ to reduce the power $4$ of $x$ in the numerator makes the life easier.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+x^4\right)}{1+x^2} d x 
= & \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+x^4\right)}{1+x^2} d x \\
= & \Re\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^2+i\right)}{1+x^2}\right)\\=&\Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^2+\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\right)}{1+x^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the particular case  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^2+a^2\right)}{1+x^2} d x=2 \pi \ln (1+a)$ in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/700000/732917), we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+x^4\right)}{1+x^2} d x 
 & =\Re\left[2 \pi \ln \left(1+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] \\
& =2 \pi \Re\left[\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]\\
& =\pi \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& =\pi \ln (2+\sqrt{2})
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: What is the R like symbol ?

Comment: R represents real part part.

Answer (score 3):

**Trigonometric Reduction**
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\left(1+x^4\right)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(1+\tan^4(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\cos^4(x)+\sin^4(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x-4\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1b}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(1-2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x-4\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1c}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(1-\frac12\sin^2(2x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x-4\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1d}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\pi\log\left(1-\frac12\sin^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x-4\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1e}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(1-\frac12\sin^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x-4\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1f}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(1-\frac12\cos^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x-4\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1g}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ substitute $x\mapsto\tan(x)$
$\text{(1b):}$ add and subtract the integral of $\log\left(\cos^4(x)\right)$
$\text{(1c):}$ $\cos^4(x)+\sin^4(x)=\left(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)\right)^2-2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$
$\text{(1d):}$ $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$
$\text{(1e):}$ substitute $x\mapsto x/2$ in the left integral
$\text{(1f):}$ apply the symmetry of $\sin(x)$ about $\frac\pi2$
$\text{(1g):}$ substitute $x\mapsto\frac\pi2-x$ in the left integral

---

**Computation of the Left Integral**
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2a}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n-1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}\sin(x)\tag{2b}\\
&=(2n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(x)\cos^{2n-2}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2c}\\
&=(2n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n-2}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-(2n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2d}\\
&=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n-2}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2b):}$ prepare to integrate by parts
$\text{(2c):}$ integrate by parts
$\text{(2d):}$ $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$
$\text{(2e):}$ add $\frac{2n-1}{2n}$ times $\text{(2a)}$ to $\frac1{2n}$ times $\text{(2c)}$

Apply $(2)$ inductively to obtain
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi/2}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\tag3
$$
To apply $(3)$ to the integral, we will use the series
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}x^n&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}\tag{4a}\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}x^{n-1}&=\frac4{\sqrt{1-4x}\left(1+\sqrt{1-4x}\right)}\tag{4b}\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\binom{2n}{n}x^n&=2\log\left(\frac2{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}\right)\tag{4c}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a):}$ the Extended Binomial Theorem
$\text{(4b):}$ subtract $1$ and divide by $x$
$\text{(4c):}$ integrate using $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sqrt{1-4x}=-\frac2{\sqrt{1-4x}}$

Finally,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(1-\alpha\cos^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\alpha^n}n\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5a}\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\alpha^n}n\frac{\pi/2}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\tag{5b}\\
&=\pi\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha}}2\right)\tag{5c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a):}$ apply the series for $\log(1-x)$
$\text{(5b):}$ apply $(3)$
$\text{(5c):}$ apply $\text{(4c)}$ with $x=\frac\alpha4$

---

**Computation of the Right Integral**

Although we can use $(5)$, with $\alpha=1$, to compute the following integral, the following approach not only displays a different method, but also is more direct and simpler.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6a}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\frac12\sin(2x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6b}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\frac12\sin(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6c}\\[3pt]
&=-\frac\pi2\log(2)\tag{6d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(6a):}$ substitute $x\mapsto\frac\pi2-x$
$\text{(6b):}$ average the two sides of $\text{(6a)}$
$\text{(6c):}$ substitute $x\mapsto x/2$
$\phantom{\text{(6c):}}$ apply the symmetry of $\sin(x)$ about $\frac\pi2$
$\text{(6d):}$ subtract $\text{(6a)}$ from two times $\text{(6c)}$

---

**The Complete Integral**
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\log\left(1+x^4\right)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\left(1+x^4\right)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{7a}\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(1-\frac12\cos^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x-8\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{7b}\\
&=2\pi\log\left(\frac{2+\sqrt2}4\right)-8\left(-\frac\pi2\log(2)\right)\tag{7c}\\[3pt]
&=2\pi\log\left(2+\sqrt2\right)\tag{7d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(7a):}$ the integrand is even
$\text{(7b):}$ apply $\text{(1g)}$
$\text{(7c):}$ apply $(5)$ with $\alpha=\frac12$ and $(6)$
$\text{(7d):}$ simplify

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\ln(x^4+1)}{x^2+1}=\sum_{n=1}^4\frac{\ln(x-w^n)}{x^2+1}$ where $w=e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$.
Applying the residue theorem with the closed lower semi-circle contour for $n=1,2$ and with the upper one for $n=3,4$, the answer will be $$2\pi i\left(-\sum_{n=1}^2\frac{\ln(-i-w^n)}{-2i}+ \sum_{n=3}^4\frac{\ln(i-w^n)}{2i}\right)=
\pi\left(\ln(2+\sqrt2)+\ln(2+\sqrt2)\right)\\=2\pi\ln(2+\sqrt2).$$

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning what intervals the arguments live in. Generally, for complex numbers, you can't always split up the logarithm like $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ willy-nilly. And a semi-circle contour doesn't seem to work here because of the branch cuts, if I'm interpreting your answer correctly.

Comment: @Accelerator So do you mean that my answer  is accidental? What is the value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x+a)}{x^2+1}dx$?

Comment: I don't know if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671716/evaluate-logarithmic-integral-int-infty-infty-frac-lnx2a2x2?noredirect=1) answers your second question, but for your first question, it seems like the equality with the two sums could hold, but it depends on what you define the branches and arguments of those logarithms to be. I wouldn't say the answer is accidental but more vague than anything else.

Comment: After doing some brutal computations, I let $b_k = \exp{\left(i\frac{\pi}{4}(2k+1)\right)}$ where $k \in \left\{0,1,2,3\right\}$ and got $\operatorname{arg}(z-b_0) \in [\pi/4, 9\pi/4)$, $\operatorname{arg}(z-b_1) \in [3\pi/4, 11\pi/4)$,  $\operatorname{arg}(z-b_2) \in (-11\pi/4, -3\pi/4]$, and  $\operatorname{arg}(z-b_3) \in (-9\pi/4, -\pi/4]$. So with these, you should be able to add the logarithms comfortably, but then there's also the issue of making the contour deal with the branch cuts.